# How to pass a string as an argument to a `do.call` command?

Tags: r

How can I pass a string (e.g. `"na.rm=TRUE"`) as an argument to a `do.call` command?

For example this works as expected:

```
> do.call(mean, list(1:10, na.rm=TRUE))
[1] 5.5
```

But what if I get the argument `na.rm=TRUE` as a string: `"na.rm=TRUE"`? If I try the following then it fails:

```
> do.call(mean, list(1:10, "na.rm=TRUE"))
Error in mean.default(1:10, "na.rm=TRUE") : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one
> do.call(mean, list(1:10, na.rm="na.rm=TRUE"))
Error in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

**So given an argument in form of a string (`"na.rm=TRUE"`), how can I use it in a `do.call` command?**

To give a bit more background, the GUI in question is for `dcast` in `reshape2`. The user can input in two separate boxes:

- the function name

  - say, `user_fun <- "mean"`, that is then passed to `dcast(fun.aggregate=get(user_fun))`
- the function args

  - say, `user_ags <- "na.rm=TRUE"`, that is then passed to `dcast(...)` via `do.call`

So at the end of the day it would look something like:

```
do.call(dcast, list(data_set, form, 
                     fun.aggregate=user_fun, user_ags))
```

As you can see, I have trouble with fitting the `user_ags` into `do.call`. For all I know the `user_ags` can contain any number of arguments in it and of any possible type (say, `user_ags <- "na.rm=TRUE, other.arg='both', yet.another=NULL"`).

So I am looking for a generic way to parse such a string, such as a `eval(parse(text=""))` approach or similar. I tried various combinations of `eval`, `parse`, `deparse`, `substitute`, all to no avail..

Comment: Your actual problem is that you have code as a string.

Comment: This is what I get from a GUI widget, and I somehow need to pass/parse that.

Comment: It would be nicer if your GUI passed name/value pairs. The `=` really kind of messes things up. Do you only need to parse named function parameters? It would help if you could be more clear about the possible inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a method that does not use `eval` but does wrap the params in a fake function call and uses `parse` to extract them

```
#sample function
myfun<-function(...) {
    print(list(...))
}

strparam <- "na.rm=TRUE, plot=F, age=15"

params <- as.list(parse(text=paste0("f(", strparam , ")"))[[1]])[-1]

do.call(myfun,params)
```

Comment: Works almost perfectly, with one small hiccup: If I do `strparam <- "na.rm=TRUE, trim=0.2"; params <- as.list(parse(text=paste0("f(", strparam , ")"))[[1]])[-1]` and then both `do.call(mean, list(1:10, params))` and `do.call(mean, list(1:10, unlist(params)))` end in error. How can I "unlist the object by one level" when passing it to `do.call`? In the second case the operation makes it lose the names..

Comment: You are combining them incorrectly. Try `do.call(mean, c(list(1:10), params))`

Answer (score 2):

If the input format follows some specification, you can always do string processing:

```
fun <- "mean"
args <- "trim=0.1, na.rm=FALSE"
args <- strsplit(args, ",", fixed=TRUE)
args <- strsplit(args[[1]], "=", fixed=TRUE)
names(args) <- gsub(" ", "", sapply(args, "[", 1), fixed=TRUE)
args <- lapply(args, "[", -1)
args <- lapply(args, type.convert)

do.call(get(fun), c(list(1:10), args))
#[1] 5.5
mean(1:10, trim=0.1, na.rm=FALSE)
#[1] 5.5
```

But it's always dangerous to allow arbitrary input.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work as expected. As for its being dangerous, of course, but no more dangerous than using `...` from the command line; so user beware..

Comment: I notice one issue with `type.convert`. If the input is `args <- "trim=0.1, na.rm=FALSE, asdf=NULL"`, then the resulting `args$asdf` is a `factor`. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: You need to check such cases using something like `lapply(args, function(x) if (x=="NULL") return(NULL) else return (x))`. There might be other problems like this.

Comment: I see. This is solution then isn't as generic as what I was hoping for.

Comment: Well, as I said, the problem should probably be solved at the input end.

Comment: I agree that this would be perfect, but I'm not sure how I can anticipate the GUI for every and any possible function in R, including user hacks..

Comment: You could also use something like `try(eval(parse(text=<...>)))` instead of `type.convert`. But that would create a more severe security risk.